# Selected dropdown value based on querystring in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, select

There is a similar question on here about this problem but i cant seem to get it working.

So when the link is clicked the url passes the value to the dropdown on this page so pre populates.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idOptions').on('change', function () {
        window.location.assign('/string.html?strings=' + $(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

<select id="idOptions">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
        <option>option4</option>
        <option>option5</option>
</select>
```

Then link below is on a different page.

string.html?strings=option1

based on this example http://jsfiddle.net/73PEg/

Answer (score 0):

just like this

on change or click event whatever you need

```
document.location.href = "http://someurl" + $("#idOptions").val();

window.location = "http://someurl" + $("#idOptions").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your code is getting the *select* value, when you need the *selected option* value.
2. Your options have no value, so you'll have to get the text of the options.

Here's the code you need:

```
$('#idOptions').on('change', function () {
    window.location.assign('/string.html?strings=' + $(this).find('option:selected').text());
    // window.location.assign('/string.html?strings=' + $(this).find('option:selected').val()); // Use this one to get the option value instead of the text
});
```

[And a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/K2KZ7/)

Comment: The selected `option`s value or text _is_ the value of the `select`: http://jsfiddle.net/8z6B9/

Comment: ok ive added value to the options tags now and using val()

is my link correct that im using 

string.html?strings=option2